# Calendar in LWUIT

Tags: java, java-me

I am using LWUIT calendar.

How can I change the the selected date in runtime?

```
        final Calendar cal=new Calendar();
        cal.setChangesSelectedDateEnabled(true);
```

Comment: `setSelectedDate(java.util.Date d)
          This method sets the Calendar selected day` [LWUIT API](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Calendar.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use setDate method of calendar class and pass a java.util date which will set the date. To reflect those changes in UI you can use refreshTheme() or revalidate() which will kind of repaint your form.